# I tried to start to use the multiprocessing module of python but is not working

Tags: python

I tried to start learning the multiprocessing module but every time I see an example online and try it, it doesn't work. For example I use this code and the python interpreter display nothing I use python 3.8.6 64 bit.

```py
 import time
 import multiprocessing 

 def basic_func(x):
     if x == 0:
         return 'zero'
     elif x%2 == 0:
         return 'even'
     else:
         return 'odd'

 def multiprocessing_func(x):
     y = x*x
     time.sleep(2)
     print('{} squared results in a/an {} number'.format(x, basic_func(y)))
    
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     starttime = time.time()
     processes = []
     for i in range(0,10):
         p = multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocessing_func, args=(i,))
         processes.append(p)
         p.start()
        
     for process in processes:
         process.join()
        
     print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Is the script just hanging or is it just exiting without output? This code ran fine for me.

Comment: How are you executing this? When you run `python test.py` (assuming you call the file test.py) what output do you see?

Comment: Works for me on linux command line.

Comment: Code works fine for me, too.

Comment: i run the programme with the run option in visual studio 2019

Comment: when i run the programme the python window pop up but nothing is display on it

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're in the process of learning multiprocessing, you almost never want to call `multiprocessing.Process` directly, especially if you're trying to set up a bunch of nearly identical processes.  In many cases, a pool is simpler.

The better way to write this would be:

```
    starttime = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(multiprocessing_func, range(10))
    print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```